# Clarification of passing params in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript and am a litte confused with passing parameters through functions, I was hoping someone could give a clearer explanation

I have the following simple code

```
     //generate random number
     var number = Math.round(Math.random()*10 + 1);

     //Ask user for name
     var playerName = prompt("What is your name?");

     //Prompt for intro
    var weclome =   alert("Hello " + playerName + " Welcome to Guess the Number");
    console.log(number);

    var playerGuess = prompt("What is your guess ");

    if (playerGuess !== null) guess(playerGuess);

   function guess(pGuess){ 
    if(pGuess == number) {
     alert("Congratulations you have guessed correctly");
    } else {
     alert("Unlucky, please try again");
  }  
}
```

As you can see its ust a simple guess the number game. From what i understand so far I have assigned the variable playerGuess as the result of the input from the prompt, which I pass through the guess function. What I dont understand is that i have called the param pGuess within the guess function. My understanding is that this should not work, but yet it does, how does pGuess know to get its value from playerGuess.

Am I looking at this in totally the wrong way, I would really like to understand this

Thanks

Comment: Thank you to all who answered, big help, sorry i couldn't accept all as answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with this line (note the `function` keyword):

```
function guess(pGuess){
```

is defining a reusable chunk of code (a "function") which takes a single parameter. When that parameter arrives, it's accessible by the name `pGuess` during the following block of code, which lasts until the matching `}`.

What you're doing with this line (note we don't have the `function` keyword any more):

```
guess(playerGuess);
```

is *calling* that function using the current value of the `playerGuess` variable. So you're passing that value into the function where it places it in the previously defined `pGuess` variable for the scope of that function call

Comment: so if i wrote guess(pGuess); then there would be no value to pass as it hasnt been defined?

Comment: Correct. The key concept here is a variable's "scope", i.e. the parts of the code where it is available. That's a keyword you can search to find more information :)

Answer (score 4):

> how does pGuess know to get its value from playerGuess

It doesn't. The value of `playerGuess` is given *to* the function by the function call, not taken from the variable by the function.

`guess(playerGuess)` means "Call the guess function. Pass the value of `playerGuess` as the first argument.

`function guess(pGuess){` means "This is the guess function. Assign the value of the first argument to the local `pGuess` variable when it is called".

Comment: might be a daft question but how is the value of playerGuess given to the function call? thank you for your answer

Comment: As I said: `guess(playerGuess)`

Comment: got it, thanks, so I am really just renaming the params within the scope of the guess function?

Comment: No. You are passing the value of the variable. Changes to `pGuess ` won't affect `playerGuess` (unless the value is a reference to an object of some kind and you modify the object).

Answer (score 1):

- The value of `prompt("What is your guess ");` is assigned to the variable `playerGuess`
- The method `guess` is called with the value of  `playerGuess`
- `pGuess` is just the internal identifier the `guess` method uses for the argument - just another variable. In this case, containing the value of `playerGuess`

Comment: might be a daft question but how is the value of playerGuess given to the function call? thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. When you're calling `guess(playerGuess)`, you're setting `pGuess` in the function.